# Get Average of a range

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to get the average of a set of numbers using a table column as the range. For some reason I can't figure this one out.

What I have so far;

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Incident ID*+]<>""),--(MONTH(Table1[Reported Date+])=MONTH(1)),--(YEAR(Table1[Reported Date+])=A2))
```

The column I want to get the average for is

> Table1[Time Count]

Comment: MONTH(1) = 1 so better to use just 1.......MONTH(2) also = 1......

Answer (score 2):

If you want average, use AVERAGEIFS. Why SUMPRODUCT???

But as you need conditions based on calculation from cells, `MONTH(Table1[Reported Date+])=MONTH(1)` and `YEAR(Table1[Reported Date+])=A2`, you will have to create one column in your source data to handle this.

Then you can simply use

```
=AVEREGEIFS(Table1[Time Count], "<>""""", Table1[Incident ID*+], MONTH(1), Table1[Reported Date+_MONTH_COLUMN]), Table1[Reported Date+_YEAR_COLUMN]=A2)
```

Why are you using `--`?

Comment: +1 for AVERAGEIFS - You don't necessarily need an extra column, though. You can use A2 to create start and end dates, e.g. for January in the year shown in A2 = AVERAGEIFS(Number_Range, Date_Range,">="&DATE(A2,1,1),Date_Range,"<"&DATE(A2,2,1))

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this yet?

```
=Average(Table1[Time Count])
```

Comment: I tried the following; =SUMPRODUCT(--(Table1[Incident ID*+]<>""),--(MONTH(Table1[Reported Date+])=MONTH(1)),--(YEAR(Table1[Reported Date+])=A2),--(Average(Table1[Time Count])))

Comment: I need to maintain the functionality it already has, e.g. selecing specific month/year.

Comment: @user1451070 Have you looked into the `AverageIfs` function yet?